# Url redirection using htacess for my website

Tags: htaccess

my website has some development issues i really need some help

When someone types www.mysite.com/mysite.com/mysite.com/anypagename.php

a page opens up which shows data of the original page but without pictures.

this problem is occurring for all pages that are in the root directory. How can i solve this using htacess redirection?

I don't know whats wrong and it is hurting my performance

Comment: You should try expanding your question a bit. It's unclear what your current code is doing. Also, please tell us what you have tried yourself so far...

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange URL structure you've got there - are you sure you're running WordPress? I'd imagine that would give a 404 if so.

If you are on WordPress, could you say what you've set in the WordPress address and Site address fields in the General Settings page, which will be at --your site URL--/wp-admin/options-general.php